# Stored iterative procedure not inserting into table

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, procedure

I'm utilizing two procedures, one to define a cursor and the second to insert the results of the first into a temporary table before inserting into the final table. I have tested my select query definition for the cursor and it is returning the results I would like; however, I am getting no values inserted into my temporary table.

### Iterative Procedure

```SQL
CREATE PROCEDURE procIteration ()
BEGIN
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE TaxonName varchar(170);
DECLARE RankID varchar(170);
DECLARE ParentID varchar(170);
DECLARE TaxonID varchar(170);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT child.SciName, RankID, parent.parentID, child.tid FROM taxa child LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(parenttid) as parentID, SciName, taxaenumtree.tid FROM taxaenumtree, taxa WHERE taxa.tid = taxaenumtree.tid GROUP BY taxaenumtree.tid) AS parent ON parent.tid = child.tid WHERE rankID = 10;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

OPEN cur;

testLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO TaxonName, RankID, ParentID, TaxonID;
    IF done THEN 
        LEAVE testLoop;
    END IF;
    CALL taxon_reclamation(TaxonName, RankID, ParentID, TaxonID);
END LOOP testLoop;

CLOSE cur;
END //
```

### Inserting Procedure

```SQL
CREATE PROCEDURE taxon_reclamation (IN TaxonNameIn VARCHAR(170), IN RankIDIn VARCHAR(170), IN ParentIDIn VARCHAR(11), IN TaxonIDIn VARCHAR(170)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE TaxonName varchar(170);
DECLARE RankID varchar(170);
DECLARE ParentID varchar(170); 
DECLARE TaxonID varchar(170);
SET TaxonName = TaxonNameIn;
SET RankID = RankIDIn;
SET TaxonID = TaxonIDIn;
SET ParentID = ParentIDIn;

INSERT INTO taxon_reclamation(TaxonID, FullName, Name, RankID, ParentID, TaxonTreeDefID, TaxonTreeDefItemID)
VALUES (TaxonID, TaxonName, TaxonName, RankID, ParentID, 2, 1);
END //
```

I should be getting a temporary table with the name of the taxon, the taxon ID, the parent ID for that taxon and its rankID (family, genus, species, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You should change names of your variables so they will be different than column names.

Comment: Hi @mrek I changed them so that it would be less confusing as to which variable or column I was referring to, but still got the same result of no insertion.

Comment: Hi @Vaughn, ok (that's not only about confusion, it just causes errors). Could you please paste the current code? Are you sure you changed both variable names RankId and ParentId? Is there no error message? Can you execute manually `call taxon_reclamation('test','test', 'test', 'test')`? Does it insert that test row?